# sudo apt-get update not available

Tags: apt, update

When I try to update with `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you added anything into /etc/apt/sources.list by any chance? Try setting all current lines to comments (with a # at the start) and then make the first line read `deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi` for buster and see if that fixes it

Comment: you may be able to fix it by running `sudo apt install apt-transport-https`

Answer (score 2):

The error message suggests to install the package `apt-transport-https`, but I'm afraid that it doesn't help much. If showing the package, you get:

```
rpi ~$ apt show apt-transport-https
Package: apt-transport-https
Version: 1.8.2.1
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Source: apt
Maintainer: APT Development Team <deity@lists.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 156 kB
Depends: apt (>= 1.5~alpha4)
Download-Size: 149 kB
APT-Sources: http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
Description: transitional package for https support
 This is a dummy transitional package - https support has been moved into
 the apt package in 1.5. It can be safely removed.
```

Https support is now in the apt package so you can try to use **apt** instead of **apt-get**:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
```